# Send multiple files over Java sockets

Tags: java, android, file, sockets

I know why my problem is occurring but I do not know how to solve it. I am sending multiple files from sender to receiver by sending the following things:

1. Number of files
2. File Name
3. File Size
4. File data(in bytes)

I am making use of `readInt()`, `readUTF()` and `readLong()` to send the first 3 in my list. 
For the file data I am making use of a buffer by implementing the following code:

```
float bytesRead = 0;
int count;
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
      out.write(buffer, 0, count);
      bytesRead += count;
      Float[] progressData = {(bytesRead / 1000), (float) (size / 1000), (float) i, (float) totalFileCount};
      publishProgress(progressData);
}
```

I am making use of a for loop to send all the details of the files.

The problem here is that after reading the first file's data, the receiver reads the next file's name also as the first file's data. I need to somehow get it to stop reading after it has reached the size of the first file. But I am unable to implement that. Any help is appreciated.

This is the code for both receiving and sending the data:

Sending

```
try {
        Socket client = new Socket();
        client.bind(null);
        client.connect(new InetSocketAddress(groupOwnerAddress, 8888));

        if(client.isConnected())
        {
            ((FileTransferActivity) context).setStatus("Connected to Device");
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());

            out.writeInt(encryptedFiles.size()); // send number of files

            for(int i = 0; i < encryptedFiles.size(); i++)
            {

                long length = encryptedFiles.get(i).length();
                if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                    System.out.println("File is too large.");
                } else {
                    out.writeUTF(encryptedFiles.get(i).getName()); //send file name
                    out.writeLong(length); // send file length

                    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(encryptedFiles.get(i)));

                    float bytesRead = 0;
                    int count;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                    while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        out.write(buffer, 0, count);
                        bytesRead += count;
                        Float[] progressData = {(bytesRead / 1000), (float) (length / 1000), (float) i, (float) encryptedFiles.size()};
                        publishProgress(progressData);

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        client.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Receiving

```
File directory = new File(directoryPath);
        if(!directory.exists())
            directory.mkdirs();

        String data = null;

            try {
                server = new ServerSocket(8888);
                client = server.accept();
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());

                int totalFileCount = in.readInt();

                for(int i = 0; i < totalFileCount; i++)
                {
                    String fileName = in.readUTF();
                    long size = in.readLong();

                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(directoryPath + File.separator + fileName));

                    float bytesRead = 0;
                    int count;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192]; // or 4096, or more
                    while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        out.write(buffer, 0, count);
                        bytesRead += count;
                        Float[] progressData = {(bytesRead / 1000), (float) (size / 1000), (float) i, (float) totalFileCount};
                        publishProgress(progressData);
                    }

                }

            }

                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

I have omitted the other functions of the asynctask here as I don't think they are relevant. In any case, if you want me to include that too, just mention it in a comment and I will update my answer with them

Comment: If you have read the fileSize into a variable you can simply compare it in the loop with `bytesRead`. If `bytesRead` is equal or larger the read fileSize you are done with the loop. When writing the file it would be good to use the same buffer size and even send some 0 bytes aofter the file end to fill up the current buffer. Then you are sure that you don't read accidentally the header of the next file in the loop.

Comment: @robert the problem I faced with that approach was that I am using a buffer of 8 bytes. And my file size isn't a multiple of 8.. so if I do what you're saying, I will lose some of the data . Right? Since it will either leave the last few bites(less than 8) or it will read a bit more . Both of which are undesirable

Comment: Use read(byte[] b, int off, int len). Bytes to read is always Math.min(buffer.length, bytesRemaining).

Comment: Also, there's no need to match buffer sizes between peers. It wouldn't work anyway, as there's no guarantee that read() will actually read the number of bytes requested.

Comment: @glenebob. I tried that but it did not help. If you have a working solution can you post it as an answer? Maybe I missed something

Comment: @NeerajAthalye, if it didn't help, please post code and what went wrong. The code you did post is pretty well guaranteed not to work.

Comment: @glenebob I have updated my question. Please have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't run this through javac, but it should work:

```
int count;
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];

while (size > 0 && (count = in.read(buffer, 0, Math.min((int) size, buffer.length))) > 0) {
    size -= count;
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
    // Progress reporting omitted.
}
```

Comment: The count thing worked. I have another question though. I didn't understand what you meant when you said `Also, there's no need to match buffer sizes between peers. It wouldn't work anyway, as there's no guarantee that read() will actually read the number of bytes requested` in your comment on my post. Can you please explain that?

Comment: The stream contract says that a read() call will return any number of bytes up to the limit provided. In practice, it depends on the stream. For example, file streams will generally return the number of bytes requested (if they're available), while a socket stream will very often return fewer bytes due to the nature of network communication. That's why read() returns the number of bytes read. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[],%20int,%20int)